# Labeled dataset for sentiment analysis in Mandarin

Tags: data-request, nlp, language, sentiment-analysis

I am doing my research on sentiment analysis for Standard Mandarin. I don't have any benchmark dataset. I need usable labeled dataset for my research.

Comment: No limitations as to the kind of sentiments?

Comment: like positive ,negative sentiment

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/didi/ChineseNLP/blob/master/docs/sentiment_analysis.md:

> [SemEval-2016 Task 5](http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2016/task5/index.php?id=data-and-tools#) contains 2 test sets with over 5000 reviews in total from digital camera and mobile phone area.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) | Size(words) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SemEval 2016 Task 5 – CAM Test | Digital Camera reviews (Chinese) | 3 | 2256 | ~25k |
| SemEval 2016 Task 5 – PHNS Test | Mobile Phone reviews (Chinese) | 3 | 3191 | ~34k |

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) | Size(words) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SemEval 2016 Task 5 – CAM Train | Digital Camera reviews (Chinese) | 3 | 5784 | ~61k |
| SemEval 2016 Task 5 – PHNS Train | Mobile Phone reviews (Chinese) | 3 | 6330 | ~62k |

> [NLP&CC 2012 Test](http://tcci.ccf.org.cn/conference/2012/pages/page04_eva.html): Chinese Weibo sentiment analysis evaluation data.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) | Topics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [NLP&CC 2012 Test](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-6880-6_29) | Weibo reviews | 2 | 1908 | 10 |

> [ChnSentiCorp](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417407001534): It contains 1021 documents in three domains: education, movie and house.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) | Size(words) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ChnSentiCorp Test | Hotel reviews(Chinese) | 2 | 1999 | ~725k |

> [IT168TEST](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I08-1040): A product review dataset presented by Zagibalov and Carroll. This dataset contains over 20000 reviews, in which 78% were manually labeled as positive and 22% labeled as negative.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IT168Test | Product review | 2 | 29531 |

> [Dianping](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/glyph): Chinese restaurant reviews were evenly split as follows: 4 and 5 star reviews were assigned to the positive class while 1-3 star reviews were in the negative class.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dianping | restaurant reviews | 2 | 2,000,000 |

> [JD Full](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/glyph): Chinese shopping reviews were evenly split for predicting full five stars.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JD Full | shopping reviews | 5 | 3,000,000 |

> [JD Binary](https://github.com/zhangxiangxiao/glyph): Chinese shopping reviews are evenly split into positive (4-and-5 star reviews)and negative (1-and-2 star reviews) sentiments, ignoring 3-star reviews.

| Source | Genre | # Classes | Size(sentences) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JD Binary | shopping reviews | 2 | 4,000,000 |

> Other Resources
>
> - Overview paper in this area:
>
>   - [chinese-sentiment-analysis-review](http://sentic.net/chinese-sentiment-analysis-review.pdf)
> - An incomplete list of new corpora (as of 2020):

| Name | Description | Domain/ Source | Size (positive/ negative where applicable) | Accuracy | F1 | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chinese Sarcasm Dataset | Text manually labelled as sarcastic or not | news | 2500 / 90 000 | 0.7611 | 0.7368 | [Gong et al., 2020](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.lrec-1.619.pdf) |
| CH-SIMS | Individually labelled multi-modal (text, video, audio) | movies, TV shows | 2281 video segments | - | 0.827 | [Yu et al., 2020](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.acl-main.343.pdf) |
| FiTSA | Aspect-based sentiment analysis for financial news | news | 8314 sentences, 647 000 characters | - | 0.798 | [Yuan et al., 2020](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.lrec-1.620.pdf) |
| MPDD | Emotion in multi-party dialogs | TV shows | 25 500 utterances | 0.595 | - | [Cheng et al., 2020](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/2020.lrec-1.76.pdf) |
| MIMN | Multimodal (text, image) and aspect-based analysis | zol.com (shopping site) | 5200 reviews | 0.616 | 0.605 | [github](https://github.com/xunan0812/MIMN) |